# How to detect a mobile browser using PHP in content?

Tags: theming

Using Drupal 7.14 with the PHP filter on I have the following in a Basic Page content type:

```
<?php if ($is_mobile == TRUE):?>
<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/a page" data-width="710" data-height="600" data-show-faces="false" data-border-color="#73AA4B" data-stream="true" data-header="false"></div>
<?php else: ?>
<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/a page" data-width="900" data-height="600" data-show-faces="false" data-border-color="#73AA4B" data-stream="true" data-header="false"></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I get the error message:

*Notice: Undefined variable: is_mobile in eval() (line 1 of D:\websites\modules\php\php.module(80) : eval()'d code).*

I sort of understand - I'm trying to grab a variable from the Drupal system but is there any way to do this? Maybe using Tokens?

Comment: To detect Mobile browsers you need to check [User Agent](http://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/) and then write your logic for different devices or use contrib modules as suggested by MPD.

Answer (score 5):

Mobile detection isn't built into Drupal or most popular themes (I think [Adaptive Theme](http://drupal.org/project/adaptivetheme) does, though).  You need to install a contrib module to do this.  Three options are [Browscap](http://drupal.org/project/browscap), [Mobile Tools](http://drupal.org/project/mobile_tools), and [Mobile Detect](http://drupal.org/project/mobile_detect).  Where you go from here depends on which module you are using.

Comment: I'm actually using the Adaptive Theme but can't see an obvious way to hook into it with using something like Browscap. Oh well - thanks for all the feedback!

Comment: Pretty sure you just need to have Browscap installed and enable the right settings.  AT may also be supporting Mobile Detect in the future.

Comment: `$is_mobile` seems like it's from the Mobile Detect module that MPD has mentioned.  Looking at the project page for that module, it looks like you also need the Mobile_Detect library.  Have you got that installed?

Comment: @Chapabu, `$is_mobile` isn't directly provided by Mobile Detect (I'm module author).  AT provides this out of the box if the Browscap module is installed/enabled.

Comment: @MPD ha...that's embarassing ;-)  I've just read the rest of that section properly on the project page and yeah.....*hangs head in shame*

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a [very simple module](https://github.com/leymannx/Drupal-Detect-Mobile) that detects mobile user agents and sets a corresponding global variable you then can access in your template.

```
function MYMODULE_init() {
  $GLOBALS['is_mobile'] = _MYMODULE();
}

function _MYMODULE() {
  // if no user agent is set
  if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
    $is_mobile = FALSE;
  } else {
    /** 
     *  check http://detectmobilebrowsers.com for updates
     */
    $is_mobile = (preg_match('/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino/i',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])||preg_match('/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i',substr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],0,4))) ? TRUE : FALSE;
  }
  return $is_mobile;
}
```

Inside your template you'ld then use it like so:

```
<?php if ($GLOBALS['is_mobile'] == TRUE): ?>
<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/a page" data-width="710" data-height="600" data-show-faces="false" data-border-color="#73AA4B" data-stream="true" data-header="false"></div>
<?php else: ?>
<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/a page" data-width="900" data-height="600" data-show-faces="false" data-border-color="#73AA4B" data-stream="true" data-header="false"></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try using [Theme Key](http://drupal.org/project/themekey) module to check for the Mobile device.
It provides flexibility for changing the theme not only based on the type of device but also can theme different parts of site based on different conditions.
Here, is a link to a [simple tutorial](http://mustardseedmedia.com/podcast/episode52) using themekey.

If you've just started to design the site, I'd recommend you use [Omega](http://drupal.org/project/omega) theme to develop, as it has an option to change layout and make it responsive (according to screen size/resolution). It also supports HTML5.
It can be well combined with [Omega Tools](http://drupal.org/project/omega_tools) module, to create an Omega sub-theme from UI.

Comment: This is a well developed site unfortunately using the Adaptive Theme. We're in cross-device checking phase and rather than redo large chunks of code I'm looking at ways to utilize what we've got. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 2):

1. In template.php put this code

   ```
   function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$variables){

     $useragent=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

     if(preg_match('/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i',$useragent)||preg_match('/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i',substr($useragent,0,4))) {
       $variables['is_node'] = "mobile";
     }
   }
   ```
2. In node.tpl.php put this code

   ```
   if($is_node == "mobile"){
     //Add your html
   }
   ```
3. After that clear the cache.

Source : [Detect Mobile Browser](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/)