# Administration theme for certain roles

Tags: 7, users

How do I force certain roles to use exclusively administration theme? These roles are only allowed to add content in administration and there is no problem for that. But some pages, like the user profil page, still use the front office theme and I need them to always use the administration theme. Any good solution for that?

Thanks

Comment: look for my answer [here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/48876/how-to-detect-a-mobile-browser-using-php-in-content/48878#48878) for a hint. Theme key module can do this for you.

Comment: thks @indrock, I will check it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look into the [hook_admin_paths](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_admin_paths/7) function where You can define the pages that should use the administration theme.

For this to work on specific roles just use something like:

```
function mymodule_admin_paths() {
  global $user;
  if(in_array('administrator', $user->roles)) { 
    //Make the changes for the administrator
  }
}
```

Comment: rerally interesting!!i am checking this

Comment: it's working fine, thks!!

Comment: Great - no prob.